# See most recently verified apps?

Tags: macos, security, verify

Recently I've had the "Verifying ..." dialog pop up on my screen for less than a second and I couldn't see what app was being verified. Here's an example of the window for Microsoft Word:
[image: apple macos verifying]

My question: **is there a way to see what apps were verified?** Like can a I see a list of the most recent ones? Command line is fine.